# Pig Latin grouping and averaging type error: error while computing sum of doubles

Tags: apache-pig, grouping

I am trying to learn Pig Latin basic grouping and averaging. Relevant chunk of schema looks like this:

```
region: chararray, balance: float
```

I am trying to find average balance of every region in a group.
Full code looks like this:

```
data = LOAD 'xademo.customer_details' USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
data = FOREACH data GENERATE region, balance as balance:float;
groups = GROUP data BY region;
avgs = FOREACH groups GENERATE data.region, AVG(data.balance);
DUMP avgs;
```

At this point, I am getting following error:

```
2016-10-02 01:34:43,081 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStats - ERROR 0: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2103: Problem while computing sum of doubles. 
2016-10-02 01:34:43,081 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRPigStatsUtil - 1 map reduce job(s) failed
```

I am not sure what exactly is wrong with my code, because groups look good to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below

```
data = LOAD 'xademo.customer_details' USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
data = FOREACH data GENERATE region, (float)balance;
groups = GROUP data BY region;
avgs = FOREACH groups GENERATE data.region, AVG(data.balance);
DUMP avgs;
```

The [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HCatalog+LoadStore#HCatalogLoadStore-DataTypeMappings) shows  the mappings between data types in HCatalog-managed Hive tables and Pig , you have to check what is the data type of balance in HCatalog-managed Hive table and accordingly you have to convert it to respective type in pig.